# WP Recommended Table Exclusions?

Tags: wpdb, export, exclude

I just re-designed my WP work flow to utilize 2 bash scripts (`push.sh` & `pull.sh`) that I wrote that will push/pull my files with git, upload/download & import/export my dbs using rsync and wp-cli.

There are 2 plugins whose settings I don't want to download/upload & constantly change whether I am work on test or production:  lite-speed-cache and ithemes security plugin respectively.  Therefore, I exclude the plugin files from git using .gitignore and I research wp-cli documentation and learned how to exclude the respective tables of those plugins.

```
# Skip certain tables from the exported database
$ wp db export --exclude_tables=wp_options,wp_users
Success: Exported to 'wordpress_dbase-db72bb5.sql'.

# Skip all tables matching a wildcard from the exported database
$ wp db export --exclude_tables=$(wp db tables 'wp_user*' --format=csv)
Success: Exported to 'wordpress_dbase-db72bb5.sql'.
```

Sorry if this is a rookie question, but I'd rather risk asking the dumb question, rather than not knowing:

**Question:**
With my previously described work flow are there other tables within the basic wp db that I should also exclude from my regular development workflow?   wp_users, etc, etc.  a specific list would be awesome.

(I get full db backups from other scripts on a regular basis, so I am looking to streamline the dbs that I pulling and pushing between test / prod.)

thanks

Comment: There isn't a generic answer. This is not a particularly common approach to begin with. It depends entirely what you have in your development database that you want or do not want in production, and that depends entirely on your workflow.

Comment: @JacobPeattie fair enough, just thought I'd thrown the line see if I catch any fish... thanks for the feedback

Comment: good explanation of basic wp tables and their usage: `https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-database-management-with-phpmyadmin/#wpdbtables`  I decided to exclude cache plugins. security plugins, and wp_users" tables

Comment: I've been in a similar position before and it's true, it'll be unique to your situation and the plugins you use, as well as what you want to accomplish with push and pull. By default, a normal backup or transfer-to-dev-site export would include all the tables — that's the most normal thing. You could consider excluding the largest tables from plugins, if they are unnecessary and have isolated data, and if you want to speed things up.